# tinted background images in reveal.js

Tags: css, image, reveal.js

I'm using [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/) to make a slide deck. I'm using background images on almost every slide, with text in the foreground. I'm trying to tint the images in the background so that they are more visible behind my slide text, using the gradient trick [discussed here](https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/), but I'm not sure where to add this code to get it working.